# Redefinition error with multiple derived classes in the main

Tags: c++, header-files, redefinition

I have an Object base class, and I have several derived classes called Item, Person, and Location.

Because each of these are derived from Object I need to include Object.h in each of their header files, and I include all of the derived classes in my main.

Because I am doing that I am getting a redefinition error.

What I want to know is what is the correct way to include these files to avoid this error?

Thanks!

EDIT:

**object.h**

```
using namespace std;

class Object{
    string name;
    string description;

    public:
        Object();
        Object(string name, string description);
        void set_name(string name);
        void set_description(string description);
        string get_name();
        string get_description();
        ~Object();
};
```

**item.h**

```
using namespace std;

#include "object.h"

class Item : public Object{
    public:
        Item();
        Item(string name, string description);

};
```

**locale.h**

```
using namespace std;

#include "object.h"

class Locale : public Object{
    public:
        Locale();
        Locale(string name, string description);
};
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "locale.h"
#include "item.h"


using namespace std;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is the *exact* error message?  And please show a (simplified) version of your code.

Comment: The exact error message is "Redefinition of Object"

Comment: Ok, you'll need to show some code.  Check out http://sscce.org first (it's about boiling your code down to the best possible format for Stack Overflow).

Comment: I know what is causing the error. object.h is getting defined twice. I want to know what the correct format for including header files is for this circumstance.

Comment: Please do not import namespaces inside header files - this is a pretty invasive thing to do, every file that includes that header will automatically import the whole namespace.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Strange, everybody I've met that hits this problem does not have a slightest idea what is going on and you have properly analysed the problem.

Read this:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard

Answer (score 8):

You should add include guards to your headers. This prevents headers from being included twice. For example, at the the top of the Object.h header, you would put,

```
#ifndef _OBJECT_H
#define _OBJECT_H
```

and then you end the header with,

```
#endif
```

If the header has already been included, the text between `#ifndef` and `#endif` is dropped.

Answer (score 4):

If you haven't got them in place already, you need to put [include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) into you header files to prevent including the same files multiple times (which would redefine the classes).